# GDBus equivalent for dbus_connection_setup_with_g_main()

Tags: c, glib, dbus, bus, gdbus

I am migrating code from dbus-glib to GDBus as the former is deprecated.
I am not able to find an equivalent function for dbus_connection_setup_with_g_main() in GDBus.
https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-glib/dbus-glib-DBus-GLib-low-level.html#dbus-connection-setup-with-g-main

Can someone point me to an equivalent function in GDBus or something which does the similar job ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same but you can use [g_main_context_push_thread_default()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-push-thread-default) if you need to change the default context for the currently running thread.

If this isn't what you wanted to do, you may have to expand the question a bit.